# Failed to parse NetParameter file in OpenCV when deploying machine learning application on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

"I'm trying to deploy my machine learning application on Heroku. It works perfectly fine locally, and the deployment is successful. However, the assigned URL is not working. The logs --tail command displays the following message:
File "/app/app.py", line 20, in 
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(PROTOTXT, MODEL)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1176: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse NetParameter file: model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel in function 'ReadNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'

I've tried everything, including changing the file location (trying absolute and relative paths), using os to verify that the file paths are correct. I've also attempted to use a different version of OpenCV (in requirements.txt, I specified opencv-python-headless==4.7.0.68).

HELP! What else can I try?"

here is part of my code:

`
app = Flask(**name**)
CORS(app)

```
PROTOTXT = 'model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt'
POINTS = 'model/pts_in_hull.npy'
MODEL = 'model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel'

print("Load model")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(PROTOTXT, MODEL)
pts = np.load(POINTS)
```

`

i tried to change paths, use other version of open cv python headless.